# convert string to utf-8 in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am having `hundeausführer` (in German) text in URL and it is giving me as `hundeausf%C3%BChrer` in console.log. How can I convert `hundeausf%C3%BChrer` back to `hundeausführer`?

I tried

```
console.log(unescape(encodeURIComponent('hundeausf%C3%BChrer')));
console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape('hundeausf%C3%BChrer')));
```

but not getting a proper answer in the console log.
Getting the same text as `hundeausf%C3%BChrer`

Anyone help me to solve this out?

Comment: Whats the `escape` for? Just decode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `decodeURI()` function

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('hundeausf%C3%BChrer'));
```

```
>>hundeausführer
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```js
console.log(decodeURI('hundeausf%C3%BChrer'));
```